# slight delay on v-if function when user is authenticated. Pinia, Vue3, Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Once user is signed and i refresh the page, there is a slight delay in showing user info. Log in button appears for a sec and then it displays user profile. Below is my code in my user.js pinia store.

```
export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
    state: () => ({
        userData: {},
        loadingUser: false,
        loading: false,
    }),
    actions: {
        currentUser() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const unsubcribe = onAuthStateChanged(
                    auth,
                    (user) => {
                        if (user) {
                            this.userData = {
                                email: user.email,
                                uid: user.uid,
                            };
                        }
                        resolve(user);
                    },
                    (e) => reject(e)
                );
                unsubcribe();
            });
        },
        async registerUser(email, password) {
            this.loadingUser = true;
            try {
                const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    auth,
                    email,
                    password
                );
                this.userData = { email: user.email, uid: user.uid };
                router.push("/");
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                this.userData = {};
            } finally {
                this.loadingUser = false;
            }
        },
        async loginUser(email, password) {
            this.loadingUser = true;
            try {
                const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    auth,
                    email,
                    password
                );
                this.userData = { email: user.email, uid: user.uid };
                router.push("/");
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                this.userData = {};
            } finally {
                this.loadingUser = false;
            }
        },
            async signOutUser() {
            this.loading = true;
            try {
                await signOut(auth);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } finally {
                this.userData = {};
                this.loading = false;
                router.replace("/authentication");   
            }
        },
        async googleSignIn() {
            this.loadingUser = true;
            try {
              const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
              const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
              const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
              const token = credential.accessToken;
              console.log(credential)
              this.userData = {};
              router.push("/");
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
              this.userData = {};
            }
             finally {
             this.loadingUser = false;
            }
          },    
          async ResetPassword(email) {
            this.loading = true;
            try {
                await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
                // alert("Password reset link sent!");
                router.push("/authentication");
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } finally {
                this.userData = {};
                this.loading = false;
               
            }
        }
    },   
});
```

my app.vue displays the current user with the below.

```
const userStore = useUserStore();

onMounted (() => {
    userStore.currentUser()
})
```

and then i use v-if to display the login button before authentication and user profile once user is authenticated. However, once user is authenticated and i refresh the page, i can see the login button for 1 second before it changes to the user profile. code for my navbar is below. I am using firebase for authentication, pinia for state management.

```
<div v-if="!userStore.userData.email">Login</div>
<div v-if="userStore.userData.email">User Profile</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once user is authenticated and i refresh the page, I can see the login
> button for 1 second before it changes to the user profile.

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), when using `onAuthStateChanged()` to set an observer on the Auth object, this object may be in "an intermediate state—such as initialization". This is why we use to check that the `user` object is not `null` with `if (user) {...}`.

It's up to you to manage this intermediate state in your front-end by , for example, showing a spinner if `user` is `null` and showing the user's data when the `user` object is not `null` anymore.